# How do I vertically align text inside an anchor element, which is nested within an unordered list

Tags: css, html-lists, anchor, vertical-alignment

I have searched extensively and seen numerous examples on how to `vertical-align` text using the `vertical-align` property and the `line-height` property. However, all my efforts seem to bear no fruit as I am unable to get my text to align vertically. How do I do vertically align text to be centered? The `height` properties are not fixed so I can't use `line-height`.

**HTML**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="html/login.html">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="html/user_registration.html">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Programmes Offered</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav
{
    height: 30%;
    width: 100%;
}

nav ul
{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}

nav ul li
{
    height: 33%;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you may use a pseudo element displayed as an inline-box using full height of li and vertical-aligned to midlle. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VsgPN/)**

```
body, html {
    height:100%; /* needed for demo */
}
nav {
    height: 50%; /* increased for demo */
    width: 100%;
}
nav ul {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
nav ul li {
    height: 33%;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px; /* show me li , for demo */
}
nav ul li:before {
    content:'';
    height:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

### edit

If you **also** reset `display` and `vertical-align` on `<a>`, links can be spread on a few lines *(demo below)*:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

nav {
  height: 70%; /* height set for snippet demo purpose, could be really too much  */
  width: 100%;
}

nav ul {
  height: 100%; /* will follow height, inherit height value , set in nav if any avalaible  */
  margin: 0px;
}

nav ul li {
  height: 33%;
  /* see me and my center*/
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px;
  background:linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 50%);
}

nav ul li:before {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="html/login.html">Login</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="html/user_registration.html">Register</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Programmes<br/> Offered</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: This worked. However, I'm not familiar with the content property, I guess my day isn't over yet. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know why, but I had to up mine to height: 110%.  I was trying to vertically center the text in an anchor tag that's absolutely positioned, and the psuedo-class :before trick worked!  Thanks!!  Was taking far too long to accomplish that.

Answer (score 5):

If you can use flexbox, you can get away with the following css:

#### CSS

```css
ul li a {
    display:flex; // Enables flexbox 
    justify-content: center; // Center on main axis
    align-items: center; // Center on cross axis
}
```

#### Update ( using [auto margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins) )

You can also do it like this:

```css
ul li { display:flex }
li a { margin: auto }
```

```css
/* These rules are just to make things easier to see. */

nav {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 5rem;
  border: 1px dotted green;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

li {
  height: 3rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}


/* Here are what I am trying to illustrate */

ul li {
  display: flex;
}

a {
  margin: auto;
  /* or adjust them one by one, by targeting 
     the ones you want and setting
     using each margin like this:
  
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
  */
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="html/login.html">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="html/user_registration.html">Register</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Programmes Offered</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

vertical-align aligns inline elements with their siblings.. unless used in a table cell.

I don't think there's a by-the-book way of vertically aligning.. but this should work:

[D E M O](http://jsfiddle.net/RGeWL/3/)

```
nav ul li
{
    background:#f1f1f1;
    height: 33%;
    width: 100%;
    border-top:1px solid #e0e0e0;
}

nav ul li a
{
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    top:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(0,-50%);
    -moz-transform:translate(0,-50%);
    transform:translate(0,-50%);

}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work. I was hoping for a simpler method that wouldn't involve transforms. Nevertheless, it hasn't worked. Vertical-alignment is such a bother ... I had no idea.

Comment: @Kis have you looked at the jsfiddle demo in the answer?

Comment: whoops I forgot to add support to browsers that aren't chrome.. I'll update the answer to this.. http://jsfiddle.net/RGeWL/3/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with

```
nav ul li a
{
    height: 33%;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: 5px; //(you can make it 10px or -10px, just so it fits your style)
}
```

Your text is within the a tag, so adding a in the css may solve your problem :)

Comment: this won't work.. it won't vertically align the A tag to the height of the LI

Comment: What do you want to do actually , I don't get it ?

Comment: I had tried it earlier and i didn't work. Ive just tried it again for a peace of mind but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I want my text to appear in the middle, currently its sticking at the top.

Comment: You can use 
vertical-align: 5px; (You can do 10px, -10px, just align it so it sticks where you want, I think this will work for you).  P.P I edited my code up so you can see

Comment: user3757576 I was avoiding the use of fixed units of measurement since i want my site to be as fluid as possible and easy to maintain. Check out GCyrillus' answer, it worked for me.