# vertical-align and pseudo element

Tags: css

To vertically center `<a>` tag i found this solution in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24351798/how-do-i-vertically-align-the-text-inside-an-anchor-tag-which-is-nested-within)

> you may use a pseudo element displayed as an inline-box using full
>   height of li and vertical-aligned to midlle. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VsgPN/)**

```
body, html {
    height:100%;/ needed for demo */
}
nav {
    height: 50%;/* increased for demo */
    width: 100%;
}
nav ul {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
nav ul li {
    height: 33%;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px;/* show me li , for demo */
}
nav ul li:before {
    content:'';
    height:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

My question why we have to use a pseudo element ?
Why it's not working when I delete the pseudo element and I put just :

```
a {
    height:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Is the `vertical-align` have to apply to a first element (`:before`) and the other (`<a>`) will follow the vertical alignment ?

Comment: as `a` tag is inline element so you made it block level element. but here is the reason as `vertical-align: middle;` only work when using `display:table-cell`. use that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why pseudo works?

With the before and after pseudo-elements, we can insert virtual elements before or after an element's content. They both work the same way, except that one inserts the content before the element and the other inserts the content after.

Pseudo elements forces some contents to be there in the html page and in the css stylesheet you apply a empty content with the height of 100% ie. with your tag height and now the content is occupying the space before or after (as you use pseudo) and to that align vertically with options top, middle, or bottom:

[try this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97d6L/) : just set `height: 100px;` and then increase manually like 200px, 300px then you will understand the exact reason

Without vertical alignment it's going to bottom as it is 100% heighty and if you use `vertical-align:middle` then you'll notice how the pseudo is working.

You may understand by seeing this picture:

[image]

Comment: i didn't get well the first part can you explain it more ?

Comment: @Aminoo simple answer is as soon you remove the `height` from `pseudo element`; vertical alignment will won't work anymore. conclusion is `height` is playing the major role here.

Comment: @Aminoo Glad, that you could understand.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

using `pseudo` element you are getting vertically center the text because of known height as you used `height:100%;` on `pseudo element.` As soon you will removed the height the layout will be broken.

As a tag is `inline element` so you made it `block level` element. but `vertical-align: middle;` only work with  `display:table-cell`. but wait you have to use `display:table` in `li` element also.

Check the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VsgPN/4/)**. so this piece of code will work..

```
a{
   height:100%;
   display: table-cell; /*replaced with display:inline-block*/
   vertical-align: middle;
}

nav ul li {
    height: 33%;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px;
    display:table; /*add this line*/
    width:100%; /*add width as well*/
}
```

Comment: My question is about to explaining why the vertical align work with pseudo element.